# Decimal to binary conversion C++

Tags: c++, binary, int, decimal

This program works fine for 3-digit integers. But it gives wrong answer when a 4 digit integer is entered.

```
convertToBinary(123); // returns 1111011 (correct) 
convertToBinary(2345); // returns 1313853193 (incorrect)
```

Here is the function which converts decimal to binary:

```
int convertToBinary(int x){
int remainder;
int i=1;
int total=0;

while(x!=0){
    remainder = x%2;
    x /= 2;
    total += remainder*i;
    i *= 10;
}
return total;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you step through the code line by line in a debugger.

Comment: May be you should first visit http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: Nitpicking: you're not really converting to binary, you're converting to a number whose decimal representation contains only ones and zeros. For instance, `convertToBinary(3)` would return eleven, not three.

Comment: @molbdnilo And the answer is 11. And binary numbers are represented using only ones and zeros btw.

Comment: @user3834119 A decimal (base 10) representation of a number, containing only ones and zeros, is not binary.

Comment: @molbdnilo what is the binary representation of 3 according to you?

Comment: @user3834119 Three in binary is 11. Eleven in decimal in 11. Seventeen in hexadecimal is 11. Nine in octal is 11. These are all different numbers. The C++-`int` written `11` is the number eleven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you run into an overflow: 2345<sub>10</sub> is 100100101001<sub>2</sub>, which exceeds the limit of 32-bit `int` that you use to store the `total`.

You could improve the range a little by using `unsigned long long` for your `total`, but some larger numbers would still trigger overflow errors. A better approach would be to use a `std::string` for the result of the conversion.

Comment: One thing is that `int` is not guaranteed to be 32-bit.

Comment: @EricZ Technically true, but no modern and common platform have an `int` that is not 32 bits.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It's certainly not very common, but at least one "modern" platform has 48 bit ints.  (Modern in the sense of still being sold today.  The actual architecture dates from the early 1960's, or maybe before.)

Comment: A bitset might also be an appropriate alternative to using an int depending on the application.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and using string helped it.
following is the code :

```
string Solution::findDigitsInBinary(int A) {
    std::string r;
    if(A == 0) return "0";
    else if(A == 1) return "1";
    else
    {
    while(A!=0) {r=(A%2==0 ?"0":"1")+r; A/=2;}
    }
    return r;
}
```